# How can I generate comments from xs:documentation tags in a wsdl?

Tags: c#, documentation, wsdl

Aloha

I received a nice wsdl with xs: documentation tags like:

```
<xs:complexType name="Supplier">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      The supplier of the product
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
```

Is there any way to generate `///<summary>` tags from this? I'm using visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the tool [xsd2code](http://www.codeplex.com/Xsd2Code) that includes this functionality.

-Edoode

Answer (score 1):

Try [the WSDL tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) from Microsoft and see if that helps