# Looking for a download location for XSDClassGen

Tags: xsd, xsdobjectgen

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386155/comparison-of-xsd-codegenerators-c) I'm looking for someone who can provide me with a link to XSDClassGen, a .NET 2.0 "version" of XSDObjectGen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not XSDClassGen, but the version in the Utilities directory from [this CodePlex project](http://ivc.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=13385) is an updated version of XSDObjectGen that support generics if that's any use to you. Thanks to some [random German page](http://translate.google.com/translate?prev=hp&hl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nldelphi.com%2FForum%2Fshowthread.php%3Fp%3D266430&sl=auto&tl=en) for the link ;-)

Comment: Thanks! BTW the original page is in Dutch (as I am) and not in German :)

Comment: Lol, was it? I guess NLdelphi.com should have been a giveaway :-)

Comment: Only place I've found linking to an updated (with source!) version of the XSDObjectGen.  Original from MS is still listed as 1.4, this is 2.0.