# Read typed objects from XML using known XSD

Tags: c#, xml, compact-framework, xsd, xmldocument

I have the following (as an example) XML file and XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<foo>
  <DateVal>2010-02-18T01:02:03</DateVal>
  <TimeVal>PT10H5M3S</TimeVal>
</foo>
```

and

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="DateVal" type="xs:dateTime" />
        <xs:element name="TimeVal" type="xs:duration" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Then the following C# code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
     XmlSchema xs;
     using (var fs = File.OpenRead(FilePath + "SimpleFields.xsd"))
     {
        xs = XmlSchema.Read(fs, null);
     }

     xd.Schemas.Add(xs);
     xd.Load((FilePath + "SimpleFields.xml"));
     xd.Validate(null);

     var el_root = xd.DocumentElement;

     var el_date = (XmlElement)el_root.SelectSingleNode("./DateVal");
     //WANTED: el_date.Value = 2010-02-18 01:02:03 (as a DateTime Object)
     //ACTUAL: el_date.InnerText="2010-02-18T01:02:03"

     var el_duration = (XmlElement)el_root.SelectSingleNode("./TimeVal");
     //WANTED: el_date.Value = 10 hours, 5 minutes, 3 seconds (as a TimeSpan Object)
     //ACTUAL: el_date.InnerText="PT10H5M3S"

     Console.WriteLine("DONE");
     Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

---

How can I read the data as strongly typed objects ?

I will be targetting a WindowsMobile device, but this shouldn't need to affect the answer too much. (can be .NET 2.0 or 3.5 ... Not sure if Sstem.Xml.Linq will help or not)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK - Found the answer I was looking for.

it is the XmlConvert class.

```
     var el_date = (XmlElement)el_root.SelectSingleNode("./DateVal");
     //WANTED: el_date.Value = 2010-02-18 01:02:03 (as a DateTime Object)
     var val_date = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(el_date.InnerText);
     //ACTUAL: el_date.InnerText="2010-02-18T01:02:03"

     var el_duration = (XmlElement)el_root.SelectSingleNode("./TimeVal");
     //WANTED: el_date.Value = 10 hours, 5 minutes, 3 seconds (as a TimeSpan Object)
     var val_duration = XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(el_duration.InnerText);
     //ACTUAL: el_date.InnerText="PT10H5M3S"
```

---

Marc's answer was correct in terms of reading in a whole strongly-typed class, but in this case I only wanted to read a single strongly-typed element/node.

Answer (score 67):

You need to do two steps:

1) Take your XML schema file and run it through the `xsd.exe` utility (which comes with the Windows SDK - it's in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\` or some similar path. This can turn the XSD file into a C# class:

```
xsd /c yourfile.xsd
```

This should give you a file `yourfile.cs` which contains a class representing that XML schema.

2) Now, armed with that C# class, you should be able to just deserializing the XML file into an instance of your new object:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(foo));

string filename = Path.Combine(FilePath, "SimpleFields.xml");

foo myFoo = ser.Deserialize(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)) as foo;

if (myFoo != null)
{
   // do whatever you want with your "foo"
}
```

That's about as simple as it gets! :-)

Comment: As marc_s had guessed, this question is related to code-generation.

I had tried xsd.exe

I had also looked at other questions such as [Comparison of xsd codegenerators - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386155/comparison-of-xsd-codegenerators-c), but most of these options seemed to use XmlSerializer.

This isn't in itself a bad thing, but I was wondering if there was another method that cave a bit more control (rather than just binding to the various events of the XmlSerializer class.

Comment: This doesn't use the xsd at runtime.  It provides no validation.

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio 2013 and I found xsd.exe util in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools.  
So:         
1. If you have 64-bit version of Windows, try to find this util in c:\Program Files (x86)         
2. See all subfolders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\ not only v6.0A