# How to serialize to XML controlling the namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to generate the following XML:

```
<Learner xmlns="some.domain.api">
  <ActivationDate>1999-05-31T11:20:00</ActivationDate>
  <EmailAddress>String content</EmailAddress>
  <ExpirationDate>1999-05-31T11:20:00</ExpirationDate>
  <FederalId>String content</FederalId>
  <FirstName>String content</FirstName>
  <Grade>K</Grade>
  <LastName>String content</LastName>
  <MiddleName>String content</MiddleName>
  <UserName>String content</UserName>
  <Password>String content</Password>
  <SISId>String content</SISId>
  <StateId>String content</StateId>
  <Status>Active</Status>
</Learner>
```

I have read these questions:

- [How can I make the xmlserializer only serialize plain xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772004/how-can-i-make-the-xmlserializer-only-serialize-plain-xml)
- [Automatically generate XSD to C# in Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990684/automatically-generate-xsd-to-c-in-visual-studio-ide)

I am using [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) to generate the classes from XSD. **That** is working.

I have tried this:

```
private static string SerializeXML(Object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), "some.domain.api");

    //settings
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    StringWriter stream = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);

    serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    return stream.ToString();
}
```

But it produces this:

```
<Learner xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="some.domain.api">
  <ActivationDate>1999-05-31T11:20:00</ActivationDate>
  <EmailAddress>String content</EmailAddress>
  <ExpirationDate>1999-05-31T11:20:00</ExpirationDate>
  <FederalId>String content</FederalId>
  <FirstName>String content</FirstName>
  <Grade>K</Grade>
  <LastName>String content</LastName>
  <MiddleName>String content</MiddleName>
  <UserName>String content</UserName>
  <Password>String content</Password>
  <SISId>String content</SISId>
  <StateId>String content</StateId>
  <Status>Active</Status>
</Learner>
```

I want to get rid of `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

How to?

**Update**

I have also already tried this using `XmlSerializerNamespaces`. If I add namespaces like this, using my implementation above with the necessary adjustments:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = 
    new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("ns","some.domain.api") });
```

I get this:

```
<Learner xmlns:ns="some.domain.api">
```

But I need this:

```
<Learner xmlns="some.domain.api">
```

If I add namespaces like this, using my implementation above with the necessary adjustments:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = 
    new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
```

I get this:

```
<q1:Learner xmlns:ns="some.domain.api">
```

for all XML tags!

Is there any way I can do to get my desired output? I really don't want to use `StringBuilder` for this task...

Comment: Provider requires. Go figure.

Comment: @marc_s Any thoughts? It seems so trivial, but I've been running around this for a few hours now...

Comment: The proper way would be to tell the other party to clean up their act and be able to parse the output of your serialization - it's absolutely positively legal XML ! Not sure if you can armwrestle the .NET XML serialization into giving you want that broken system needs....

Comment: I know it is legal XML. And your suggestion sounds sensible. But, is it such a hassle to get the output the way their specs show?

Comment: @marc_s Liked your comment a lot, BTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as you did up there with:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = 
new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("ns","some.domain.api") });
```

and after writing the file do this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file_name);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
content = Regex.Replace(content, ":ns", "");
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file_name);
writer.Write(content);
writer.Close();
```

Not the most elegant, but it works.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's not elegant, but I *think* I like it :)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use an empty name for the namespace:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = 
new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("","some.domain.api") });
```

Then you add them for the serialization process:

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, namespaces);
```

Thats all to omit the "ns:".

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
 public static string SerializeObject(object obj)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces XSN = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        XSN.Add("bs", "some.domain.api");

        XmlWriterSettings XWS = new XmlWriterSettings();
        XWS.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter xtWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false));

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(xtWriter, obj, XSN);

        xtWriter.Flush();

        stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(((MemoryStream)stream).ToArray());

        return xml;
    }
```

**updated**

You can always replace the returning xml string "xmlns:bs" to "xmlns" if you are forced to a fixed xml output syntax!

Comment: Your solution is ignoring the settings. And the output root is `<Learner xmlns:bs="yournamespace">`. I need to have it = `<Learner xmlns="yournamespace">`

Comment: Because it's ignoring the settings, it is not omitting XML declaration. More over, your solution does not provide indentation,  `XWS.Indent = true;` is missing.