# Is there anything I can do if a Service Reference is not working?

Tags: c#, web-services, paypal

I'm trying to get a reference to Paypal's API at https://www.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl but adding it as a service reference or as a web reference brings up

```
charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported     method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<?xml     version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
ns:version="76.0"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes"
xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes"
targetNamespace="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
<wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <import namespace="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" schemaLocation="CoreComponentTypes.xsd"/>
        <import namespace="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" schemaLocation="eBLBaseComponents.xsd"/>
        <import namespace="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" schemaLocation="En'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I feel like it's more likely I'm doing something wrong than paypal's API is broken.
The tutorial I'm following doesn't mention anything about what to do in this case and none of my research is turning anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runnning wsdl manually:

```
Error: There was an error processing 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalS
vc.wsdl'.
  - The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - The 'maxOccur' attribute is not supported in this context.
```

The wsdl isn't very .NET-friendly, it seems.

Comment: So what should I do? The only other option the site had was an xsd or something like that and it caused the same error.

Comment: @Brian I would try everything here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386155/comparison-of-xsd-codegenerators-c

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out later today.

Comment: Change maxOccur to maxOccurs. Typo in the WSDL.