# XSD to C# Converter

Tags: c#, xsd, converters

I have used JAXB and Ant Script to convert XSD to Java classes. After that i have used Java to C# code converter tool. Below is one of the C# code from the generated with the comments

```
//JAVA TO C# CONVERTER TODO TASK: Most Java annotations will not have direct .NET equivalent attributes:
//ORIGINAL LINE: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) @XmlType(name = "Java.city") public class AdxpCity extends ADXP
public class JavaCity : Java
{


}
```

Should i convert commented `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) @XmlType(name = "Java.city")` (or) Can i use above class as it is?

Answer (score 3):

The better thing to do is convert from XSD to C# directly via [`xsd.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) which gets installed with visual studio.

The most basic form would be

```
 xsd.exe yourFile.xsd /classes
```

however if you review the documentation you can customize further options like the default namespace the class will be generated inside.

There are also other 3rd party code generators listed [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386155/comparison-of-xsd-code-generators/4731379#4731379) that have more features than `xsd.exe`, I have personally used [xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) and found it very good to use.

Comment: I did try to locate xsd.exe but not able to locate this file to access. My machine was running with visual studio 2013. May i know where should i download and add this in VS 2013?

Comment: In the start menu click `Visual Studio Tools` this should open a folder, from there go to `Developer Command Prompt for VS2013` that should open a new console window. That console window should have `xsd.exe` included in its `PATH` variable so you can just type it from any folder and not need to include the full filepath of the program. The actual file can be found under ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v#.#A\bin\NETFX #.# Tools\`` folder (The `#`s will be replaced with a number on your system)